# export pde solution to non-uniform grid

Tags: pde, matlab

After exporting the solution (u) and the mesh (p, e, t) from pdetool to workspace, I need to compute the solution at a set of predefined points. These predefined points where the solution is sought are not uniformly spaced and are scattered in the xy space. I know that if one has the solution (u) from pde toolbox, it can be exported to a uniform grid using either [griddata](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit,) :

```
[u1,x1,y1] = gridfit(x,y,u,xnodes,ynodes)
```

or the function [tri2grid](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/pde/ug/tri2grid.html) . I believe both gridfit and tri2grid need the output sampling points to be monotonically increasing which unfortunately is not my case. How do I export/interpolate the solution to a non-uniform/scattered grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To interpolate/extrapolate solution on a uniform grid to a non-uniform grid, or vice versa, using the [$\mathtt{TriScatteredInterp}$ class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterpclass.html) is the way to go.

Let say your `u` is associated with nodes: `p`, an array size $(\text{ # of nodes})\times (\text{Dimension})$, is originally where your solution `u` is defined on, so that `size(u,1) = size(p,1)`. The the following commmand let you create an interpolant class (abstractly):

```
uI = triScatteredInterp(p(:,1),p(:,2),u,'natural');
```

for two dimensional data, or

```
uI = triScatteredInterp(p(:,1),p(:,2),p(:,3),u,'natural');
```

for 3D data. I personally prefer `'natural'` as method here, `'nearest'` is not that nice for PDE solution, and `'linear'` will result in loss of interpolation near boundary where two sides data are needed.

Now to get the values on the non-uniform grid, what is best about `triScatteredInterp` class is that it works like a function, you can use `feval` to evaluate like a function handle: say your non-uniform grid points are array `q`

```
 uInterp_at_q = uI(q(:,1),q(:,2));
```

in 2D or

```
 uInterp_at_q = uI(q(:,1),q(:,2),q(:,3));
```

in 3D. And `uInterp_at_q(i,1)` is the value of the interpolant associated with the $i$-th node `q(i,:)`.

---

Notice mathworks' doc says that

> `TriScatteredInterp` will be removed in a future release. Use `scatteredInterpolant` instead.

The usage will almost the same, just `scatteredInterpolant` has an extra extrapolation method switch.